# How to read string column in format ‘15Aug21:12:45:24’ as time stamp in Tera data?

Tags: string, timestamp, teradata, date-format

I have a character column in teradata table with format like this - ‘15AUG21:06:38:03’. I need to convert this column into time stamp so that I can use this column in order by statement. I am using teradata sql assistant to read data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `TO_TIMESTAMP`:

```sql
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP ('15AUG21:06:38:03', 'DDMONYY:HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: @Aman Use `HH24` in the format mask, in this case.